# Where should I place a new mouseListener in the main method to animate CarShape left or right when the mouse is clicked?

Tags: java, swing, animation, awt, mouse-listeners

Below is my code.  I'm new to java.swing and java.awt.  Do I need to put in a new action listener as well as a mouseListener?  Because the shape is moving I'm not exactly sure how to set this code up.

```
public class Animation {

    private static boolean goingRight = true;
    private static int posRight;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final MoveableShape shape = new CarShape(0, 0, CAR_WIDTH);
        ShapeIcon icon = new ShapeIcon(shape, ICON_WIDTH, ICON_HEIGHT);
        final JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(label);
        frame.pack();
        ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                if (posRight <= 0) {
                    goingRight = true;
                }
                if (posRight >= 300) {
                    goingRight = false;
                }
                if (goingRight) {
                    shape.translate(1, 0);
                    label.repaint();
                    posRight += 1;
                } else {
                    shape.translate(-1, 0);
                    label.repaint();
                    posRight -= 1;
                }

            }
        };
        final int DELAY = 100;
        Timer time = new Timer(DELAY, taskPerformer);
        time.start();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    private static final int ICON_WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int ICON_HEIGHT = 100;
    private static final int CAR_WIDTH = 100;
}
```

Comment: 1 important should be to explain us your idea, how do you wan to use mouseevent for animation, e.g. ShapeIcon will follows the mouse Cursor, etc 2. if statement in ActionListener is wrong. 3. label.revalidate(); before label.repaint();

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The code works currently.  The car moves right until x = 300 and then subtracts 1 until x = 0.  I would like to modify my existing main method to change directions if the mouse is clicked inside the CarShape.  I don't really need to keep the current code that checks for the direction and either adds or subtracts.

Comment: I would like to modify my existing main method to change directions if the mouse is clicked inside the CarShape. == nothing about in your code posted here :-), then ...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment.  Would you like me to restate the question?

Answer (score 0):

Could you include the code for the MoveableShape and ShapeIcon? This makes it easier to run your code and see what it is doing.

If you want to change the direction of the car when it is clicked, you could add a mouse listener to the label that contains the car shaped icon:

```
    label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent e) {
            // Change the direction here...
        }
    });
```

The car should now change direction whenever you click on the label, which is the rectangle surrounding the car.

(In the example above, I've used a MouseAdapter which allows you to only implement the methods of the MouseListener interface that you need, the others do nothing.)